# Different results in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below code in JavaScript (not showing the HTML Part, but it works).

```
var textboxnumber1 = document.querySelector('.number1');
var textboxnumber2 = document.querySelector('.number2');
var calcbutton = document.querySelector('.calcbutton');

var num1 = Number(textboxnumber1.value);
var num2 = Number(textboxnumber2.value);

function writenumbers() 
{
    window.alert(num1);
}

calcbutton.addEventListener('click', writenumbers);
```

This returns me 0 as the num1 value,

However, If i replace `window.alert(num1);` with `window.alert(Number(textboxnumber1.value));` i get it's value correctly.

Why `num1` is not showing the value?

Comment: Remember that Javascript is not Haskell - evaluations are not lazy.

Comment: Use your browser's debugger.  Place breakpoints outside of the function where you set a value to `num1` and inside the function where you display the value.  What do you notice about the order of events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code to retrieve the text box value is OUTSIDE of your function, so it will only run once at load. At page load the value is 0.

Move this code to inside the function:

```
function writenumbers() 
{
    var num1 = Number(textboxnumber1.value);
    var num2 = Number(textboxnumber2.value);

    window.alert(num1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call your function on click, the num1 variable is not assigned, but if you declare it inside the alert method it work so try this :

```
   function writenumbers() 
    {
        var num1 = Number(textboxnumber1.value);
        var num2 = Number(textboxnumber2.value);
        window.alert(num1);
    }

    calcbutton.addEventListener('click', writenumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

@UncleDave's answer is correct, but why?
Because this code:

```
var num1 = Number(textboxnumber1.value);
```

Will be evaluated first thing when page loads, and set the initial value of `textboxnumber1` in variable `num1`.
Now wherever you used `num1` in your code it'll always be the same (the initial value of `textboxnumber1`) it's assigned by value not by reference.